# Foreign key constraint on two columns to restrict ALTER and INSERT to certain values

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys

In postgres I want to restrict the possible insertion and altering of a value in a certain column to a given combination in another table.

I have `table A`. `user_id` is unique, `project_id` is not unique.

```
-- table A
default_project_id    user_id    place    start         ...
1                     1          Berlin   01.01.2023    ...
1                     2          Rome     01.01.2023    ...
2                     3          Rio      ...           ...
3                     4          ...      ...           ...
3                     5          ...      ...           ...
```

Then there is `table B`. `user_id` nor `project_id` are not unique.

```
-- table B
project_id     user_id
1              1
2              1
3              1
2              2
5              3
4              4
9              4
1              ...
```

Now, I want to add a `CONSTRAINT` to table `A` that does the following:
Only allow `default_project_id` for a `user_id`, that has a matching `project_id` and `user_id` combination in table `B`. I thought a foreign key constraint on the two columns `default_project_id` and `user_id` on table `A` referencing `project_id` and `user_id` on table `B` would do it, but I get a

> There is no unique constraint matching given keys for references table table B

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Actually I have provided a wrong value intentionally to show that error but the `alter` query should work fine. Did you try the query for your use case?

Comment: @mandy8055 nope, it is not working. I can add the `unique constraint` on my data (here: table `b`), but when I try to add the `fk constraint` (here table `a`) I get `forgein key references-columns list must not contain duplicates`.

Comment: Can you run this once please: `SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE (default_project_id, user_id) NOT IN (SELECT project_id, user_id FROM B);` Looks like there are some orphaned records in `tableB`

Comment: @mandy8055 this returns 0 results. My tables are currently very short. Table `A` has only one row while table `B` has four rows.

Comment: Hmmm...makes sense, I was surmising that the query should work for you. Not sure why it's not.

Comment: Please provide a DDL for creating the tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK):

> A foreign key must reference columns that either are a primary key or form a unique constraint. This means that the referenced columns always have an index (the one underlying the primary key or unique constraint); so checks on whether a referencing row has a match will be efficient. (...)

So the reason you get the error `There is no unique constraint matching given keys for references table table B` is because you don't have `unique constraint` on the field pair `project_id`, `user_id`. While none of them is unique in your database, I daubt there is a need to have the same project assigned to the same user twice, so the pair (`project_id`, `user_id`) should be made unique. This may be done by adding a [UNIQUE CONSTRAINT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-UNIQUE-CONSTRAINTS).

```
ALTER TABLE B
  ADD CONSTRAINT user_in_project_unique UNIQUE (user_id, project_id);
```

After that you can create a foreign key.

```
ALTER TABLE A 
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_users_project 
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id, default_project_id) REFERENCES B(user_id, project_id);
```

Comment: I tried that. Adding the constraint on table `B` works. But when I try to add a fk constraint on table `a` I get `forgein key references-columns list must not contain duplicates`

Comment: the error `forgein key references-columns list must not contain duplicates` indicates you provide duplicates in the column list of the foreign key you are creating. I'll add the example of FK creation script in the answer.